# Summary of definitions of cryptographic variables and operands

Tags: encryption

I have recently developed a fascination for cryptography since I looked at some of the complicated questions on this Stack Exchange website. I'm a good portion through [Crypto 101](https://www.crypto101.io/), but it's getting more and more inconvenient to have to look up what each operand and variable does or means (respectively). Is there any good summary or Cheat-Sheet that defines rather basically common things like `E: Encryption Function` or `⊕: XOR`? I understand this is a very novice question, but I have to break out of being a beginner somehow. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just a note: Plenty of notation is used to mean different things in different contexts, so many times you'll have to consult the definitions page of whatever you're actually reading

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen a cheat sheet for anything cryptography-specific but most, if not all, you can find in a math symbols cheat sheet. For example [Wikipedia math symbols list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) also lists the XOR function.